# How to reset angularjs character count binding in form

Tags: forms, angularjs, binding, character, reset

I have multiple form fields in an angular view that count down characters as the user types. However, I have a button/link that should reset all the form fields and character counts. When clicked, the form is reset but the character counts are not updated to reflect the change. I know there has to be a model connection I am missing here (I'm an angular newbie). I also know it's probably best to rest the form using `$setPristine();`, but I am unable to get that to work.

Here's what I've got: http://embed.plnkr.co/5SGjqPhYYIZF1qp0QAAT/preview

I'd appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your reset button isn't updating the Angular model values your character count calculations rely upon.

Instead of using `reset` on the `form` element, just clear the model values:

**HTML:**

```
<a href ng-click="clearForm()">RESET</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.clearForm = function() {
  $scope.TA3 = '';
  $scope.TA4 = '';
}
```

[Revised Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCRXyw0HCRS4Ko2cMrCq?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Nice and simple- thought I had tried this, but the call to `clearForm()` function but not execute based on the scope. Also my clearForm call was outside the form tags - in your example it works both ways, but in mine it only works when the reset link is within the form tags. Not sure why that is.